# Need help reading a text file from a path using Kotlin with Windows

Tags: android, kotlin

I am not able to find a text file on my local Windows computer to open it in Kotlin - Android Studio.  I tried placing the file in an assets folder and I tried various path variations but nothing so far.  Some code examples use either the application.open command or something that requires Context.  I don't know what to import to enable those commands.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you intend for the text content to get to the Android device? Is your intention to package it with the app?

Comment: Good question.  I would like the file to be in an assets folder within the app.  However, I am open to any solution at this point.

Comment: "I would like the file to be in an assets folder within the app" -- then do that. Use `AssetManager` and its `open()` function to get an `InputStream` on the asset. You get an `AssetManager` by calling `getAssets()` on any `Context`. See [this](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/blob/v2.0/DiceLight/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/diceware/PassphraseRepository.kt) and [this](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/-/blob/v2.0/PdfProvider/src/main/java/com/commonsware/jetpack/pdfprovider/MainMotor.kt).

Comment: https://gist.github.com/r0b0t3d/492f375ec6267a033c23b4ab8ab11e6a // for file path doc